# Understanding Parallel Nsight OutOfRangeLoad Exception

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nsight

I just ran Nisght 2.2 with Enable memory checker option and got the following error:

`CUcontext  blockIdx WarpIndex  PC         Active Mask Exception       Exception Details`

`0x02af1c10 (0,0,0) 0      0x0001cc70  0x00000004  OutOfRangeLoad   MemorySpace=Global Size=4`

Moreover, the output is below:

GPU State:

### Address  Size      Type  Mem       Block  Thread         blockIdx  threadIdx      PC  Source

05500e20     4    adr ld    g           0       2          {0,0,0}    {2,0,0}  000170  No source available

## Summary of access violations:

Nsight Debug
Memory Checker detected 1 access violations.
error = access violation on load (global memory)
blockIdx = {0,0,0}
threadIdx = {2,0,0}
address = 0x05500e20
accessSize = 4

## Nsight Debug

CUDA Memory Checker detected 1 threads caused an access violation:
Launch Parameters
    CUcontext    = 026f1c10
    CUstream     = 03460f58
    CUmodule     = 047e7538
    CUfunction   = 047c26b0
    FunctionName = _Z19findHowManyBeforeWiPcPiS0_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_ii
    gridDim      = {1,1,1}
    blockDim     = {256,1,1}
    sharedSize   = 128
    Parameters:
    Parameters (raw):
         0x05500400 0x05500800 0x05500c00 0x05500000
         0x05501200 0x05500600 0x05500a00 0x05500e00
         0x00000004 0x00000005
GPU State:

### **Address  Size      Type  Mem       Block  Thread         blockIdx  threadIdx      PC  Source**

05500e20     4    adr ld    g           0       2          {0,0,0}    {2,0,0}  000170  No source available

However, I cannot make sense of any of this info, except the fact that the error occurred in function HowManyBeforeWi for thread 2. Is there anyway to find the exact line in which the error occured because this does look very vague.

Comment: Try compiling with debugging symbols on. `cuda-memcheck` reports line numbers on debugging builds when out of bounds accesses are detected. One thing that immediately jumps out is the shared memory size reported is 128, but the block has 256 threads. Are you sure that out of bounds shared memory access during a global memory load isn't causing the problem? The kernel function prototype looks to be `findHowManyBeforeWi(char*, int*, int*, int*, int*, char*, int*, int*, int, int)` and the pointer arguments from debug look superficially valid, but without a repro case it is very hard to say more.

Comment: @talonmies: How to compile with debugging symbols on? As I am using VS 2008, I have set the GPU Debug information to -G. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I don't use visual studio or nsight, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger breaks at the line where the access violation was thrown. Alternatively, you can use the Disassembly pane to correlate where the issue occurred with the Program Counter (PC).